# ArcGIS crashes with no error number in Visual Studio

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio, serious-application-error

I've been developing Add-ins for a while with Visual Studio 2008 and ArcGIS 10.
But in my new Add-in development process, I receive no error from Visual studio and ArcGIS crashes with error "Arcgis encountered serious application error and need to be closed".

I tried setting breakpoints and the program stops correctly at the breakpoint. But when I use F8 to proceed, I can identify the line which has the error but no error screen from Visual studio appears, as normal.

Can you help me? This way I can't debug and specify exact problem in my code

Comment: can you post part of code?  This is not uncommon, and could be any number of errors in the ArcObjects code.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is put Try..Catch blocks in your code. This will make it much easier to figure out why the code is crashing. Here is an example

```
Private Sub FindSmallestPolygon()

    'This requires the feature class to be in a geodatabase 
    'or has the field "Shape_Area" already calculated with the area

    Dim pLayer As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer = My.ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.Layer(0)
    Dim pFLayer As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayer
    Dim pFClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass
    Dim pFCursor As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor
    Dim pQFilter As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilter
    Dim pFeature As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature
    Try
        pFLayer = pLayer
        pFClass = pFLayer.FeatureClass
        pQFilter.WhereClause = Chr(34) & "Shape_Area" & Chr(34) & " = (Select Min(" & Chr(34) & "Shape_Area" & Chr(34) & ") from " & pFLayer.Name & ")"
        pFCursor = pFClass.Search(pQFilter, False)

        pFeature = pFCursor.NextFeature
        MsgBox(pFeature.OID)

    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The message box should give you an indication of what's gone wrong in the code without crashing ArcMap and often contains the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: I'm aware of Try/Catch block. Maybe i haven't expressed my problem properly. I'm in development process, so i need to know where might be prolematic codes. Providing good information for user while preventing from ArcMap crash is something else. Execution should be stopped in Visual studio with a yellow line indicating the place of problem and a message containing error no, but i don't see this. I just see a big window in ArcMap which says it has crashed. was it clear? @JeremyFon

Comment: When I leave out Try/Catch blocks, I will more often get a total crash of ArcGIS with no explanation. I've done other things in the Catch block, such as bringing up a dialog box that allows the user to send me the error message via email

Comment: User? Now, there is no user except me, i.e. developer and while i'm running (=testing=debugging) my Addin via Visual studio, It must tell which line has error and which error. Isn't it?

Comment: It might be helpful to post the code that is giving you a problem

Comment: It doesn't matter which code. Suppose this in VB.NET: MsgBox ( "a" + 1). This line causes an error and Visual studio must show me this line in yellow but i don't receive any error from VS. I just see ArcGIS (which load by VS) crashes.

Comment: OK...I put that in a code with no Try/Catch block and ArcMap crashed. I put that into the Try/Catch and I get the error "System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "a" to type 'Double' is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)

etc. " and ArcMap doesn't crash

Comment: Thanks kenbuja. Now, i got what u say. Although i was looking for a way to force Visual Studio to pause the program in debugging mode (which lets me evaluate me variables, etc.), according to your suggestion i can get number of error, at least. Thanks any way

Comment: You can always set a breakpoint in the Catch block, which will allow you to look at the variables in your code when it hits an error.